# "....when a string of character is needed in the next to last statement" in toString() explanation

Tags: java, integer, double, tostring

What does the author try to tell us about the `toString()` method in this excerpt:

> The `toString()` method of the `Integer` class is automatically used
>   when a string of characters is needed in the next to last statement.
>   The `toString()` method of the `Double` class is automatically used when a
>   string of characters is needed last statement.

when discussing this code:

```
Integer value = new Integer(103);
Double dvalue = new Double(-32.78);

System.out.println( "Integer object holds: " + value );
System.out.println( "Double  object holds: " + dvalue );
```

Comment: The "next to last statement" it is referring to is in the accompanying code: `System.out.println( "Integer object holds: " + value );` where an Integer is concatenated with a string so that it can be printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The toString() method of the Integer class is automatically used when a string of characters is needed in the next to last statement.

There is code accompanying the text you quoted. The next to last statement in the code is:

```
System.out.println( "Integer object holds: " + value );
```

where `value` is an instance of `Integer`.

To perform the concatenation `"Integer object holds: " + value`, the `value` must be converted to a string. The `toString()` method of `Integer` is invoked to perform this conversion.

Similarly the statement:

```
System.out.println( "Double  object holds: " + dvalue );
```

involves invoking the `toString()` method of `Double` to convert `dvalue` to a string.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Is there any difference with double? Since "The `toString()` method of the `Double` class is automatically used when a string of characters is needed last statement. " while for `Integer` is next to last statement. Any difference?

Comment: In the code given on the website, the next to last statement is the one printing out an Integer. The last statement is the one printing out a Double. It's just telling you which line in the code it is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

@khelwood gave a good explanation. The author is trying to tell you that

```
System.out.println( "Integer object holds: " + value );   and 

System.out.println( "Integer object holds: " + Integer.toString(value));
```

are identical.

Comment: Actually `value.toString()`, not `Integer.toString(value)`, since `value` is an `Integer`, not an `int`.

Comment: Thank You @Eritrean